# EF Core Reference specific entity from one to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core

There are following EF entities:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Membership
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; } //enum->int conversion
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

according to business rules:

1. client has many memberships
2. but only one of this memberships can be active

both will be requested frequently with client info.

its easy to apply the first requirement, adding `IEnumerable<Membership>` field to a client.
But I wonder how to apply a second one...
I'm sure there definitely should be a way to receive a single active membership (or null) and store it in the property...

Could you please advise a way to request the client with its active membership by a single query?
Something similar to `client.Memberships.FirstOrDefault(m => m.IsActive)`... But where should I put it?

P.S. please assume that rule is already applied to a write side (there is no `client` with many `active` memberships)

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 5 a new feature is added, you can add `Where` inside the `Include` function, so for your example you can use:

```
 _dbContext.Clients.Include(e => e.Memberships.Where(e => e.IsActive == true).Take(1)).ToArray()
```

and make sure to add a navigation property to `Client`

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
}
```

be informed that you cannot use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where` inside `Include`, so I used `take(10)` to select one item.